# What is the response if there is insufficient space for a file uploaded using drive.file.upload

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am uploading a large file to the drive. I have noticed that if there is insufficient space in the drive to hold the file, the file upload hangs after uploading the whole file without giving any response.

Is this the default behavior ? and so should I check the available space before uploading ?

I'm using the Drive v3 API on Node.js

Comment: Did you implement your own callback errors and [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff)?

Comment: I did implement a simple error handler on the callback. Also the code doesn't retry once failed.